# QObject as a field of another QObject?

Tags: qt, qobject

We usually write QObject-derived classes that own other QObjects like this:

```
class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) 
    : QObject(parent), bar(nullptr)
    {
        bar = new Bar(this);
    }
private:
    Bar *bar;
};
```

However, when reviewing a colleague's code, I've found instead this pattern:

```
class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) 
    : QObject(parent)
    { }
private:
    Bar bar;
};
```

It appears to work as intended, but is it actually safe to do so, barring an obvious "don't `bar->deleteLater()`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe to do, so long as you don't try to delete bar as it will be automatically released upon the deletion of Foo.

Arguably, the decision of which way to go depends upon what actually `Foo` and `Bar` are.

I'd be more inclined to use the 2nd method when `Bar` is a composition of a class. In this case, it's part of it, meaning that without Bar, Foo doesn't make sense.

In contrast, if Bar is an aggregated class, a pointer to its object is more practical. In this situation, where Bar is Null, Foo still exists in its own right.

An example would be where Foo is a Car and Bar a driver. A car may or may not have a driver, but is still a car, so a pointer in the car would make more sense. In addition, this allows for changing the driver in the car, by simply changing the pointer to it.

Comment: Say, `Foo` implements some functionality that requires consulting with the network, and `Bar` is `QTcpSocket`. Is it aggregation or association?

Comment: If the object Foo can still be classed and function as the object, without a Bar, then it's aggregation. If Foo needs Bar to make sense as an object, then it's composition. Don't worry too much about the terms. Instead, think of the lifetime of the objects. If Bar is a QTcpSocket, should Foo exist without a Bar or can Foo use a different Bar? If yes, then use a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The better question is: why prematurely pessimize your code by the extra indirection of the `bar` being a pointer? The second way is not only safe (why wouldn't it be?), it's preferred for reasons of locality of reference, heap fragmentation, etc. The only thing missing from the second code fragment is the initialization of bar's parent. You need to do that if you ever wish to move a `Foo` instance to another thread. By not doing it you're prematurely and arbitrarily limiting the functionality of `Foo`.

In C++11:

```
class Bar : public QObject { ... };

class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
private:
    Bar bar { this };
};
```

Comment: Won't that cause double-destruction of `bar`? Once in `~QObject()`, and once more in compiler-generated "call members' destructors" piece of `~Foo()"?

Comment: @Joker_vD No, it won't. I don't understand where this widespread misconception came to be. `QObject` doesn't have infinite memory of its children. If you destroy any of an object's children, it immediately forgets about them; any other behavior would be nonsense. Thus, once `bar.~Bar` has run, you're in the clear. The Foo base `~QObject` will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

This should be safe. As you indicate you should of course not delete bar as it will be deleted by Foo's destructor. Care should be taken if a parent is set on bar so that double deletion does not occur.

Comment: As Kuba Ober stated, your last sentence is not true. Setting a parent on a (non-pointer) Object member variable is fine (its not strictly necessary, but can be helpful for things like maintaining proper thread affinity after a MoveToThread call on the parent). Once it is deleted, the QObject destructor will not try to delete it again.

Comment: @ScottG It's only fine, is parent of the member variable QObject is the enclosing QObject. It is not unconditionally fine. If parent is something else, and gets destructed first, it'll crash and burn.

Answer (score 0):

It is save and 100% valid. There is however the limitation that the second piece of code will only work if `Bar` has a constructor that takes no arguments.

However, if the constructor of `Bar` requires arguments you still need to create it as part of the initialiser list of the constructor of `Foo`.

```
class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) 
    : QObject(parent)
    , bar(arg1, arg2)
    { }
private:
    Bar bar;
};
```